# How can I read errors and warnings in IntelliJ with a screen reader?

Tags: intellij-idea, accessibility, screen-readers

I am using IntelliJ Idea for developing scala and Java programs. I am also a screen reader user.

One of the most useful features that IDEs provide is code linting and displaying error and warnings in your code, along with descriptions. I understand if you are a sighted user, you can just hover your mouse over an erroneous line of code and you get a tooltip with the description.

I haven't been able to figure out how to access this description as a screen reader users. So far, to review errors/warnings I would just build the program and look at the command line output, however this is pretty inefficient compared to just hovering over line of code.

Could someone share a better way of reviewing errors/warnings in IntelliJ using a screen reader? Ideally how to access the error tooltip, or how to access a better UI for reviewing them instead of looking at raw command line output.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, turn to Jetbrains.com... They have a large forum space where you get answers quickly.

Comment: Have you tried F2 ?
I'm also a screen reader user. So far I haven't got great success using IntelliJ; I'm using Eclipse.
In Eclipse, F2 opens a popup where you can read local errors and it also suggests fixes.
By chance it's maybe the same in IntelliJ... or not.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I will give JetBrains forums a try if no luck here.

@QuentinC greetings, I enjoy your playroom quite a bit. I have used eclipse in the past and it is perfectly accessible. however for work my team uses IntelliJ. pressing F2 does indeed take you to next error/warnings, however that's all it does. it doesnt actually read the tooltip.

Comment: If it does not work with F2 on Windows with JAWS or NVDA screen readers for you (See [Set up a screen reader](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/accessibility.html#screen_reader) on information about supported readers and OSes), please vote for this request in the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-195092

Comment: @Andrey thanks, but I already completed set up for using screen reader on that link. F2 does navigate to error/warning, but my issue I cant figure out how to access the tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importantly, make sure to turn on screen reader support:
settings (ctrl + alt + S) > appearance and behaviour > Appearance  > Support screen readers (requires restart)

Then when your caret is on an error/warning, you can press ctrl + F1 and a dialogue will pop up with the description. Press escape to close it.

If you want to make sure the caret is on an error/warning, use F2 to jump to next error/warning.

As noted by lukaszgo1 in his answer, the description is also printed to status bar, but NVDA cant find it using its normal command, because JAB GUI applications are lacklustre in their implementation of accessibility, however if you want to access the status bar of IntelliJ to read the description you can use [an NVDA addon which I developed](https://github.com/SamKacer/IntelliJ_NVDA_Addon), that adds a command for reading IntelliJ status bar and fixes list items not being labelled properly.

I actually forgot I asked this until I got an answer recently.

Thanks to lukaszgo1 for his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about warnings however errors can be accessed in two ways:
Firstly when the caret is moved into a line with error the error text is written into the status bar - the problem with this approach is that for JAB applications screen readers are generally unable to find it, so in case of NVDA object navigation has to be used.
The second way requires your caret to be exactly at the point with error - generally it would be set in the proper place if you've navigated to the line with F2. After that you need to press CTRL+f1 - focus moves to the unnamed pane and the error text is its first descendant so once again you need to employ object navigation. I haven't found any reasonable way to access error texts with JAWS  sadly.